# How to open an exe. file with action in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I would like to create one action where I can Exe. the FSP VIEWR to open a image where I can see in 360 degrees.

I tried these 2 options but they didn't work:

1- open ('C:/Users/FSPViewer64.exe')=[%photo%]
2- os.system ('C:/Users//FSPViewer64.exe')=[%photo%]

---

[image: Attributes table]

Well, here you can see that the "photo" is a field where I have the full paths to access the images.

Comment: Sorry i would like to open in Qgis, forget Arcgis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the file path inside the command:

```
os.system("C:/Users/FSPViewer64.exe [%photo%]")
```

Comment: Done! Thank you!! It's working perfectly!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Python action such as:

```py
import subprocess

softwarepath = "F:\\path\\to\software.exe"
picturepath = "D:\\testpic.jpg"

subprocess.Popen([softwarepath, "[%photo%]"])
```

Note that the filepath must be correctly stored inside the attribute table (using double backslash or single forwardslash, just like in the picturepath variable) and the variable `[%photo%]` must be enclosed by quotes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you have several different images that you want to open with your software:
you create a field named "lien" in a Qgis layer in which you paste the full paths to access the images.

on this same layer, you create an action like on the capture. [image]

Comment: Hi fcka I tried but didn't work. I have a fiel named photo where I have the full paths to acess the images. I did the same thing but the result is an error saying "it's not possible to execute the comand"

Answer (score 0):

@Jigar Narotomo, you have to create a layer and associate a path with each object.

[image]

[image]

[image]